# What is $\sum_{i,k=1}^n x_k^2x_i^2$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

I stumbled over the double sum $$\sum_{i,k=1}^n x_k^2x_i^2$$ and was wondering whether this is anything that can be expressed in terms of the euclidean norm?

Maybe it is even $||x||^4$ but I am not sure.

Comment: It is $\left( \sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 \right)^2 = ||\textbf{x}||_2^4$.

Comment: Which equals $||x||^4$ as proposed in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it the sum of all $n^2$ combinations of $i,k$?

So, if $n=3$:

$$\sum_{i,k=1}^3 x_i^2 x_k^2 = \\
x_1^2 x_1^2 + x_1^2 x_2^2 + x_1^2 x_3^2 + \\
x_2^2 x_1^2 + x_2^2 x_2^2 + x_2^2 x_3^2 + \\
x_3^2 x_1^2 + x_3^2 x_2^2 + x_3^2 x_3^2$$